# Copy eml file to Exchange outbox folder to send mail

Tags: exchange

I think I remember that once I found browsing on the internet that you could copy a .eml file to the outbox folder of exchange in order to send it.

Now it would be nice to have this behavior in an application I'm developing but I can't find any information related.

Am I right or I am starting to imagine weird things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [technote](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306043) explains it.  You can write the eml files to the pickup folder.